# ¿JavaScript cambiar el tamaño de un contenedor en tiempo real con el ratón?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, jquery-plugins

```
<div>
  <canvas>
    "grafico chartjs"
  </canvas>
</div>
```

La historia es necesito que el usuario pueda cambiar el tamaño del contenedor del grafico de forma visual con el ratón, utilizando medidas pre-configuradas del grill del bootstrap.
Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: La pregunta tal y como está es demasiado amplia, faltan detalles. ¿Qué quieres decir con medidas pre-configuradas, que cambie dando saltos a base de cambiar el número de columnas? Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] de bienvenida a SOes para aprender cómo se espera que se hagan las preguntas y que añadas un [mcve] de tu escenario para que nos sea más sencillo ayudarte, al menos el código que crea el gráfico.

Comment: Que tal si el div le pones de clase **col-md-4** al canvas le pones **width: 100%** y en donde quieras cambiar el tamaño solo vas cambiando de clase el div contenedor del canvas

Comment: Gracias. ya lo voy a mirar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podes resolverlo de manera muy sencilla con [jQueryUi](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#default), te dejo un ejemplo

```js
$( function() {
    $( "div" ).resizable();
  } );
```

```css
div{
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  
}
canvas{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div>
 <canvas>
 </canvas>
</div>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

saludos

Comment: Gracias si así lo hice al final.